# botbuilder LuisRecognizer not working behind proxy

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I wrote a custom recognizer.

```
bot.recognizer({
  recognize: function (context, done) {
  var intent = { score: 1.0, intent: 'Greetings'};
      if (context.message.text.toLowerCase() == 'hello' ) {
        done(null, intent);
       }
    }
});

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, (session)  => {
    session.send("Sorry couldn't understand");
});

// here is the dialog
bot.dialog('Greetings', [(session, args, next) => {
    sesson.send("hey there");
}]).triggerAction({
    matches: 'Greetings',
    onInterrupted: function (session) {
        session.send('hey there');
    }
});
```

When I type "Hello" in the emulator it replies with `hey there`. It works.

But when I try using Luis API it does not work. It replies `"Sorry couldn't understand".`

```
const model = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/**?subscription-key=***&verbose=true";
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(model);
bot.recognizer(recognizer)
```

I try the following in the terminal (node>) it does not work.
[here is the doc I followed](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.luisrecognizer%20%22here%22%20is%20the%20documentation.)

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var model = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/***?subscription-key=***&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=330&spellCheck=false";
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(model);
recognizer.recognize(
  "hello",
   model,
  function (err, intents, entities) {
    console.log(intents);
  }
)
```

The Luis Model url works perfectly fine, returns proper intents, tested it in the browser.

How to debug?

Comment: Not sure what "it does not work" means. Please provide details about the error, your luis model, if you trained and published it, etc.

Comment: Have you reviewed https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS/?

Comment: Yes, I did. can proxy be a problem here?

Comment: I figured out that the issue is due to the proxy, updated the question title. I could solve it using https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-tunnel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import globalTunnel from 'global-tunnel';

process.env.http_proxy = 'http://proxy:80';
process.env.https_proxy = 'http://proxy:80';
globalTunnel.initialize();
```

add `globalTunnel.end()` after adding the recognizer `bot.recognizer(recognizer)`

it worked.